# Где найти пакет PyQT5 с версией 5.15.11?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pip, pypi

У меня версия PyQT5 = 5.15.9

Как я понял [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWebEngineWidgets/QWebEngineView.html#) доступен с версии 5.15.11
Но казус заключается в том, что pypi имеет только версию 5.15.9 вот [пруф](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/#history). Где мне можно найти версию 5.15.11?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто устанавливайте, всё нормально работает :)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А то я бы сам долго искал как этот пакет называется :) Уже из исходников хотел было переустановить

Comment: Так в доках у вас там на блок-схеме написано `QWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView`

Comment: Да, но просто в коробке с пакетом не идет я пробовал вводить через установку, что, то наподобие названий, но  это как пальцем в небо тыкнуть может получиться и я угадаю, а может нужно множественное число :)